# Массив с разными типами с помощью memcpy()

Tags: c++, c

Задача - создать массив с разными типами переменных, численность элементов заранее неизвестна.
Пытаюсь помощью memcpy создать массив, с разными типами данных,  например такой:

```
char * packet;
float a=1.56;
int b=5;
memcpy(packet,&a,4);
memcpy(packet,&b,4);
```

Но возникает ошибка `segmentation fault`
Подскажите пожалуйста, это вообще таким способом реализовать или я в корне что то неправильное пытаюсь сделать?

Comment: Вы бы лучше озвучили задачу, а то очень похоже, что у Вас [Ошибка XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/176217).

Comment: *"создать массив с разными типами переменных"* -- а как вы собираетесь хранить информацию о типе каждой переменной в таком массиве? Без неё он будет бесполезен.

Comment: Если нужно хранить совершенно любой тип, то посмотрите на [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html). Если есть какая-то иерархия из хранимых типов, то можно использовать (умные) указатели. Всё это в качестве типа для `std::vector`, например. Правда, я подозреваю, что это будет для Вас сложно на текущий момент.

Comment: @infernalcucumber  Эта фраза  "Задача - создать массив с разными типами переменных, численность элементов заранее неизвестна"  не имеет смысла. Приведите точную формулировку того, что  требуетс. А фраза, которую вы привели, она просто безграмотная с точки зрения программирования.:)

Answer (score 3):

```
char *packet;
/* ... */
memcpy(packet,&a,4);
```

Вы объявили указатель, но не выделили память, на которую он указывает.

Либо:

```
char packet[4]; // или сколько вам надо
```

либо:

```
char *packet = new char[4]; // или сколько вам надо
```

P.S. А вам точно `C++` нужен в этом случае?

Comment: Спасибо, можно и си конечно. Вариант, если задать размерность массива сразу работает. Но у меня тут проблема, что я не знаю какая у него будет размерность заранее, поэтому рассчитываю добавлять по мере...

Comment: Значит, надо где-то хранить текущий размер, и растягивать при необходимости. Для `C` это [realloc](http://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=realloc) (не делать классическую ошибку с потерей указателя если `realloc()` вернёт `NULL`), для `C++` - `new`/`memcpy()`/`delete`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете и ошибку, и в корне неверное :)

На ошибку вам уже указали - вы не выделили память, и пытаетесь писать непонятно куда.

Но после того, как вы запишете в выделенную память - что вы хотите делать с этим дальше? Зачем эти мучения? Ведь вам нужно где-то отдельно хранить информацию наподобие:

```
Элемент 0 Смещение 0 тип double
Элемент 1 Смещение 8 тип char
Элемент 2 Смещение 9 тип int
```

B все это годится только для POD - т.е., грубо говоря, типов старого доброго C, но не C++. Вопрос: во имя чего эти мучения?

Сформулируйте свою сверхзадачу - возможно, ее можно решить куда проще...

Comment: думаю, человек изобретает protobuf (или что то подобное)

Comment: @KoVadim Или попросту велосипед...